# How to use a query mongoose in Service class with feathersjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose, feathersjs

I try to do mongoose query in my Nodejs project with feathersjs. I would like to use mongoose query in Service class like other commonly service like: find, get, update etc.

Below is my schema model:

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', size: 'string' });

const messageModel = mongoose.model('message', schema);

module.exports = messageModel;
```

I know that I can use this forms:

```
  app.use('/messages/:id', service(options), function(req, res){

  message.find({ name: req.params.id }, function (err, result) {
   if (err) return err;
   res.json(result);
  })

  });
```

but for me is better use Service class and use mongoose query in this way:

```
'use strict';

const service = require('feathers-mongoose');
const message = require('./message-model');
const hooks = require('./hooks');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

class Service {

  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options || {};
  }

  find(params) {

  message.find({}, function (err, result) {
   if (err) return err;
   return Promise.resolve([]);
  })

  }

  get(id, params) {

  message.find({ name: id }, function (err, result) {
   if (err) return err;
   return Promise.resolve([]);
  })

  }

}

module.exports = function() {
  const app = this;

  const options = {
    Model: message,
    paginate: {
      default: 5,
      max: 25
    }
  };

  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/feathers');

  app.use('/messages', new Service(options));

  // Get our initialize service to that we can bind hooks
  const messageService = app.service('/messages');

  // Set up our before hooks
  messageService.before(hooks.before);

  // Set up our after hooks
  messageService.after(hooks.after);
};

module.exports.service = Service
```

Something is wrong because it can't work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a promise in a callback. Instead, asynchronous calls that use a callback have to be wrapped in a `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {})`.

```
find(params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    message.find({}, function (err, result) {
     if (err) {
      return reject(err);
     }
     return resolve(result);
    });
  });
}
```

Tools like [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com) can make it easier to convert callback based APIs into promises automatically.

Comment: Thanks! It works very nice. I have yet one questions. If is needed an options? I try to direct an object to constructor but in a method an options is not defined. For example: `console.log (options)`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You don't have to add `constructor` (or any other method for that matter) if you don't need it.

Comment: I mean that using feathersjs by default generated service with mongodb is a constant `const options = { Model: model, default: 5, etc. }` this constant is direct to service in this way: `app.use('/messages', service(options), function(req, res){ ... });` In my case I need direct this options to constructor of my Service class called their same as default method by: `app.use('/messages', new Service(options));` but if mine collection has more than 5 documents, they are shown all. How can I show only 5 documents using constant options?

Comment: If you are implementing your own service you will have to do that yourself. You can have a look how the existing adapter does it in https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-mongoose/blob/master/src/service.js

Comment: OK, at the moment I don't need any option in my project but in the future maybe I'll need it. I'm going to save your link, thanks!

Comment: https://docs.feathersjs.com/databases/extending.html might also be relevant for you.